# Changing the Presentation of Highslide Iframe

Tags: highslide

I am experimenting with Highslide at the moment, and currently very impressed.

I have been able to customise the gallery to exactly what I want, but I am having less luck with an iframe. The pop-up appears with a header with a "Close" link in the top right corner and also a resize icon in the bottom right corner.

I can remove the header and footer with

```
.highslide-header {
display: none;
}
.highslide-footer {
display: none;
}
```

in the CSS, and I could play around with other settings in the CSS. However I can't find a way to put the "Close" link into the footer. (I would like to Close to be bottom right.)

Any guidance would be gratefully received.

MY FINAL SOLUTION
After working away at EarlyOut's suggestions I was still having problems. The final solution was to remove the header and footer as mentioned above and then place the "Close" link in the caption (which is a special custom overlay). This required just one little bit of extra code in the html, so that the thumbnail link became

```
<a href="URL_of_the_target_file" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { 
        objectType: 'iframe', width: 665, 
        height: null } )"></a>
<div class='highslide-caption closer'>
<a href="#" onclick="return hs.close(this)">CLOSE</a>
</div>
```

I added the "closer" class because it seemed the easiest way of formatting the "Close" link.

Answer (score 0):

This example should lead you in the right direction. Note the overlay positioning and added CSS for the "close" buttons:

http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/example-iframes-different-closebuttons.html

Comment: Thanks EarlyOut. I'm not quite there yet though. As I said I can remove the header and footer completely with the CSS. The bit I can't find is where is the code that creates the Close link in the header. If I could find that, I imagine I could move it to the footer.

Comment: The code is all right there on that demo page. The hs.registerOverlay places the button (change "top right" to "bottom right"), the CSS classes do the fine positioning, and the close.png file is part of the standard Highslide distribution. The close button isn't being placed in the header or footer at all - the overlay is on the main expander frame itself.

Comment: Getting there! My only problem now is that the new "Close" link appears on gallery pop-ups as well, where I don't want it. I found the useOnHtml parameter in the reference page, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a useOnHtmlButNotOnAnythingElse parameter.

Comment: You need to define two separate slideshow groups - one with the close button, the other without it. The regular images would be part of the slideshow group without the overlay.

Comment: I tried, but I just couldn't get my head around it. Highslide may be simple to those who are intimately involved in it, but I have found customising it to be difficult and confusing. I eventually solved my problem by putting display:none on the header and footer and then placing the "Close" link in the caption which wasn't otherwise being used.